# xampp controle panel not showing stop button for Apache and MySQL

Tags: apache, xampp

I have installed xampp server in D: directory, when I click on xampp icon its working and starting Apache and MySQL with auto start, But its not showing stop button when I want to stop that running process.

[image]

And when i try to start it as administrator

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your xampp version is too old,

would you try install a latest version to see whether support or not:

```
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/XAMPP%20Windows/
```